# Changing elements (like fixed logo) color, depending on the section in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, colors

I want to achieve an effect like [this one](http://aerolab.github.io/midnight.js/)
in a React webpage but without using jQuery. I've looked for alternatives to that library, but without results. I've seen a lot of similar questions, but each of them are answered using jQuery.

The effect is basically changing the color of the logo (and other elements in the page) as I scroll down through different sections.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

A way this could be done is by centering the logo's to their own containers dynamically, kinda like simulating position fixed, but using position absolute, so each logo is contained in their own section, and not globally like position fixed would do.
This way when you scroll to the next section, the second section covers the first section making it look like its transitioning.

I created a proof of concept here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/9k4o3zoo

NOTE: this demo is a proof of concept, it could be improved in performance by using something like request animation frame, and throttling.

Code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  handleScroll = e => {
    if (!this.logo1) return;
    const pageY = e.pageY;

    // 600 is the height of each section
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      y: Math.abs(pageY),
      y2: Math.abs(pageY) - 600
    }));
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  }

  render() {
    const { y, y2 } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <section className="first">
          <h1
            className="logo"
            style={{ transform: `translateY(${y}px)` }}
            ref={logo => {
              this.logo1 = logo;
            }}
          >
            YOUR LOGO
          </h1>
        </section>
        <section className="second">
          <h1
            className="logo"
            style={{ transform: `translateY(${y2}px)` }}
            ref={logo => {
              this.logo2 = logo;
            }}
          >
            YOUR LOGO
          </h1>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CSS would be:

```
section {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: helvetica, arial;
  font-size: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.first {
  background: salmon;
  z-index: 1;
}

.first .logo {
  color: black;
}

.second {
  background: royalBlue;
  z-index: 2;
}

.second .logo {
  color: red;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 230px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. It works like a charm in Firefox, but it doesn't work on Chrome or Safari. I'll try different things using your solution as a starting point and I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: Have you tried using requestAnimationFrame? its a great way of animating at 60fps, it would also be nice if you can share your code and see what we can do about it

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I haven't, but I'll try it. Thank you for your answer.